# Searching a List<string> for values with a wildcard

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, linq

I currently have set a list of the orgs the user has access to, to a list (`List<string> userOrg`).

The list contents look something like:

```
34598
34599
23%
```

I then populate a gridview using this list, so the gridview will give me all info for:

```
34598
34599
everything that starts with: 23
```

Now I want to somehow give the user the ability to search that gridview

They are putting in the org they want to find into a text box, it populates just fine, but how do I make sure to only display the orgs they have access to?

I guess what I'm asking is, how can I search through the list of user orgs to make sure the org in question is in it, but at the same time take in account the wildcard.

For example, if they search for" 345% I only want to show them 34598 and 34599, but NOT 34566, because those are the ones the user has access to (that are in my userOrg list)

I started with this, but not sure how to handle the wildcards:

```
List<string> org = new List<string>();
    List<string> userOrg = new List<string>();
    userOrg = (List<string>)Session["UserOrgs"] ;

    if (txtOrg.Text == "")
        Session["UserOrgs"] = userOrg;              
    else
    {
        foreach (string item in userOrg)
        {
            if(Regex.IsMatch(item, txtOrg.Text))
               org.Add(txtOrg.Text);
        }
        Session["UserOrgs"] = org;
    }
    ObjectDataSource1.Select();
```

Now if I put in 23% into the text box to search for all orgs that I have access to and that start with 23, it matches and goes into the if, however if I put in
2% into the textbox, it does not match with 23% that O have in my userOrg list and returns nothing.

Maybe there's a way to do it easier with LINQ? I have not done much with it before.

Comment: Why would you not want to show 34566 for a search of "345%"?

Comment: because the user does not have access to it.

Comment: if the user doesn't have access to it (34566), why do you populate it in the gridview in first place?

Comment: i wouldn't, that's what i'm trying to do. if they search for 345 i want to EXCLUSE 34566, but don't know how to check if it's in the userOrgs list that i have set up using the wildcards

Answer (score 0):

In general, I'm adverse to using regexes when standard string operations will do fine, as I'm firmly of the opinion that the latter is easier to understand, and therefore more maintainable.  In this case, I'd be tempted to do something like:

```
Bool isVisible = userOrgs.Any(delegate(string x)
                              {
                                  String y = txtOrg.Text;
                                  if (y.EndsWith("%"))
                                  {
                                      return x.StartsWith(y.TrimEnd('%'));
                                  }
                                  if (x.EndsWith("%"))
                                  {
                                      return y.StartsWith(x.Trim('%'));
                                  }
                                  return x == y;
                              }
```

If regexes are your thing, then feel free to add them as you see fit.